# Sort an array with PHP to generate a multilevel menu listing

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I am trying to generate a list of multilevel menu in PHP but I have not got how to do it, I would like to help me with simple examples and sort Categories and Sub categories with their title, something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Category 1</li>
  <li>
    <h4>TITLE HERE</h4>
    <ul>
      <li>Category Child 1</li>
      <li>Category Child 2</li>
      <li>Category Child 3</li>
      <li>
        <h4>TITLE HERE</h4>
        <ul>
          <li>Category child 1</li>
          <li>Category child 2</li>
          <li>Category child 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Category 1</li>
  <li>Category 2</li>
  <li>Category 3</li>
</ul>
```

**I have an array in PHP:**

```
$data = Array (
  '0' => Array (
      'id' => '1',
      'id_parent' => '',
      'name' => 'Sports'
  ),

  '1' => Array (
      'id' => '2',
      'id_parent' => '1',
      'name' => 'Football'
  ),

  '2' => Array (
      'id' => '3',
      'id_parent' => '1',
      'name' => 'Bascket'
  ),

  '3' => Array (
      'id' => '4',
      'id_parent' => '',
      'name' => 'Health'
  ),

  '4' => Array (
      'id' => '5', 
      'id_parent' => '4',
      'name' => 'Nutrition and diet'
  ),

  '5' => Array (
      'id' => '6',
      'id_parent' => '4',
      'name' => 'Beauty Salon'
  ),

  '6' => Array (
      'id' => '7',
      'id_parent' => '',
      'name' => 'Films'
  ),

  '7' => Array (
      'id' => '8',
      'id_parent' => '7',
      'name' => 'Armageddon'
  ),

  '8' => Array (
      'id' => '9',
      'id_parent' => '7',
      'name' => 'Apocalypse'
  ),

  '9' => Array (
      'id' => '10',
      'id_parent' => '',
      'name' => 'News'
  ),

  '10' => Array (
      'id' => '11',
      'id_parent' => '10',
      'name' => 'International'
  ),

  '11' => Array (
      'id' => '12',
      'id_parent' => '11',
      'name' => 'News from Syria'
  ),

  '12' => Array (
      'id' => '13',
      'id_parent' => '11',
      'name' => 'News from Palestine'
  )
);
```

**I have a table in MySQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_parent` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `FK_categories_UNIQUE` (`name`),
  KEY `FK_categories` (`id_parent`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_categories` FOREIGN KEY (`id_parent`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
)   ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of categories
-- ----------------------------

INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('1', null, 'Sports');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('2', '1', 'Football');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('3', '1', 'Bascket');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('4', null, 'Health');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('5', '4', 'Nutrition and diet');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('6', '4', 'Beauty Salon');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('7', null, 'Films');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('8', '7', 'Armageddon');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('9', '7', 'Apocalypse');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('10', null, 'News');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('11', '10', 'International');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('12', '11', 'News from Syria');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('13', '11', 'News from Palestine');
```

Comment: do you want to display your values in a tree like structure in html ?

Comment: @Lambda7 If you want to display that in an HTML structure

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of levels in your categories? If so, you can get the records via SQL, and in order. Then do a break-sort to generate the HTML output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to help you, but I would love to to say couple of things first;

Your database design is not proper. if you are giving **parent_id** for each element you should have given parent_id `0` or in best case `null` for top parent too. That way we could reduce first `foreach` and just fetch main categories automatically.

Maybe now you have very a few values but in future you should consider this. Think about that if you had thousands of news, categories and each time you have to loop through all the data.

Anyway here is your code

```
$parents = array();

foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
    if($item['id_parent'] === '') {
        $parents[$key] = $item;
    } 
}

?>

<ul>

<?php foreach ($parents as $parent) { ?>
     <li> <?php $parent['name'] ?> </li>
     <ul>
   <?php foreach ($data as $key => $item)  { ?>
        <?php if ($parent['id'] == $item['id_parent'])  { ?>
        <li> <?php $item['name'] ?> </li> 
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul> 
<?php } ?>
```

and this is the result

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, for your help your example is simple and very explanatory, but it will be possible to show the categories of children of the category International father, "Without changing this, adding it as a second form" else, I would like to know if there are more ways To do this using native PHP functions http://php.net/manual/es/ref.array.php, but please do not change this answer which is very useful.