# Create a menu list dynamically from php array with subelements

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array with menu items and submenu items. The submenu items are set with a parent ID and depth. An example array looks like this:

```
[0] => stdClass Object ( [CategoryID] => 4 [ParentCategoryID] => -1 [Depth] => 1 [Name] => Menu1
[1] => stdClass Object ( [CategoryID] => 2 [ParentCategoryID] => 4 [Depth] => 2 [Name] => Submenu1 
[2] => stdClass Object ( [CategoryID] => 3 [ParentCategoryID] => 4 [Depth] => 2 [Name] => Submenu2 
[3] => stdClass Object ( [CategoryID] => 1 [ParentCategoryID] => -1 [Depth] => 1 [Name] => Menu2
```

Now I want to have the array output as a list and sublist like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Menu1
        <ul>
            <li>Submenu1</li>
            <li>Submenu2</li>
        <ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        Menu2
    </li>
<ul>
```

I was not able to get those submenus to the parent element. Is there any way to do this in an easy way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort an array with PHP to generate a multilevel menu listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046731/sort-an-array-with-php-to-generate-a-multilevel-menu-listing)

Comment: Parent category has ParentCategoryID equal to - , is that ?

Comment: can you have for example a categrorie that the ParentCategoryID is 4  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop your array `$a` like this,

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    // assuming depth = 1 is only for parent categories
    if ($v->Depth == 1) {
        echo "<li>";
        echo $v->Name;
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($a as $k1 => $v1) {
            // checking inner loops parent category with outer loop's category id
            if ($v1->ParentCategoryID == $v->CategoryID) { 
                echo "<li>";
                echo $v1->Name;
                echo "</li>";
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "</li>";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Try running in PHP script.